# Elegant way with SQL Statement to INSERT based on queried list from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, recursive-query

I have a table `persons` in a MySQL 5.6 database like this:

```
persons
---------------------------------------------------
| id           | name           | sports          |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1            | Adam           | Football,Hockey |
| 2            | Ben            | Hockey,Tennis   |
| 3            | Charlie        | Basketball      |
| 4            | Dennis         | Hockey,Baseball |
---------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the column `sports` is a string, but contains a list. The reason `sports` is a string list is because the table was created from an automation step I cannot influence.

I want to find all Persons who like a certain sports type. Searching through the sports string column with `%LIKE%` is of course inefficient.
I want to leave the table as it is but for the purpose of searching for persons who like a certain sports type with efficiency, I want to fill a new M:N table `persons_sports` like this:

```
persons_sports
---------------------------------------------------
| id           | person_id      | sports          |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1            | 1              | Football        |
| 2            | 1              | Hockey          |
| 3            | 2              | Hockey          |
| 4            | 2              | Tennis          |
| 5            | 3              | Basketball      |
| 6            | 4              | Hockey          |
| 7            | 4              | Baseball        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Of course I can write a script getting all rows from `persons`, parsing the `sports` column and then fill the new table but I wonder if there is a nice and elegant way to do this via a SQL statement on the database server directly?

Comment: Precise MySQL version? Max. `sport` values per column amount?

Comment: Do you have a separate sports table with a list of sports?

Comment: *I wonder if there is a nice and elegant way to do this via a SQL statement on the database server directly* Use JSON_TABLE() if available in your MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina: Thanks for the question, I've edited my question. It's MySQL 5.6

Comment: You answers to the first question but ignores second one...

Comment: @Akina: it's VARCHAR(255)

Comment: I had asked about neither datatype nor column length.

Comment: Max. entries in the list is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table that contains the lists of sports, you can do this with `find_in_set()`:

```
select p.person_id, s.sport
from persons p
inner join sports s on find_in_set(s.sport, p.sports)
```

If you don't, then it is more complicated. One option is to use a recursive cte (available in MySQL 8.0) to iteratively split the strings:

```
with recursive 
    data as (select id, concat(sports, ',') sports from persons),
    persons_sports as (
        select 
            id, 
            substring(sports, 1, locate(',', sports) - 1) sport,
            substring(sports,locate(',', sports) + 1) rest
        from data
        union all
        select
            id,
            substring(rest, 1, locate(',', rest) - 1),
            substring(rest, locate(',', rest) + 1)
        from persons_sports
        where locate(',', rest) > 0
    )
select id, sport from persons_sports
```

Comment: The table `persons_sports` is empty at first. Can this be modified in a way to fill the table?

Comment: @Norbert: sure: `insert into persons_sports(person_id, sport) select < the above query >`